# Can two distinct events occur at precisely the same moment in time?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time, simulations

I am writing a simulation and am having difficulty resolving the order in which two distinct forces occur. The simulation will give different results if the forces are applied to the state in different orders. However, computationally I cannot make them occur at the same time.

I believe I am missing some understanding about whether the world works in continuous time or discrete. I suspect this has something to do with the speed of propagation of information, and relativity, but I'm not sure.

If two distinct events can occur at the same time, how does one write a discrete time simulator without prioritising forces?!

**Some more background:**

Suppose the state is represented by $\\S_i \in \Omega$ at time $\\i$, where $\\i \in  \mathbb{N}$. Suppose there is a state transition function $\\f: \Omega \to \Omega$ such that

$$\ S_{i+1} = f(S_i) $$

$\\f $ is modelled by the combination of two forces, G and H. G and H can each be modelled by two transition functions $\\g: \Omega \to \Omega$ and $\\h: \Omega \to \Omega$.

As far as I can determine, there is no way to compute the resultant force of two arbitrary forces (G and H). What I would like to do is define $\\f$ to be the composition of $\\g$ and $\\h$, the question is whether that should be $\\g \circ h$ or $\\h \circ g$.

Comment: Define *"event"*. The only physics usage of that word is in relativity, where it simply denotes a spacetime point, and doesn't "occur". Also, why is your question tagged with GR/SR tags?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, what about events in colliders? :D

Comment: But, what's your problem with the forces? If they act simultaneously on your system, don't they have a resultant? What does that have to do with the world time being discrete or continuous? For the computer you use some time-step, and if the time-step is enough small, probably the result is good. Can't you tell us what is the problem for which you write the simulator? Maybe we can help with some advice.

Comment: @PhotonicBoom: Ah, these crude experimentalists. I admittedly forgot that usage, but it also doesn't really fit here.

Comment: @PhotonicBoom : it seems to me that Cammil has just computer problems.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I do believe there is something going on here that relates to GR/SR.

Comment: @Sofia: No, I don't just have computer problems. Computer problems certainly motivated by enquiries. Newton didn't just have apple problems.

Comment: @PhotonicBoom : Cammil has the problem how to write a program and you seek for him GR issues? Why?

Comment: @cammil : can't you refine your question giving us some more details on the exercise that you have to solve?

Comment: @Sofia It was a joke. Plus I never mentioned GR, all I said was the word *events* is used in particle physics as well.

Comment: @PhotonicBoom : I am a computer engineer. When Cammil said simulator my mind rushed to debugging.

Comment: Edited. Though not really sure that my edits help!

Comment: A discrete time event simulator worth its water throws an error message when that happens and invokes an error handling routine. Having said that, DTES are NOT good models for physics, they are barely useful for electronics design and such.

Comment: Surely there are no alternatives for simulation. Continuous time using DEs is still discrete time as far as a computer is concerned. Unless there is a closed form solution of a future state, but then that's not really simulation is it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific coding techniques.

Comment: @BMS: i've just read the guidelines and the question does not appear to be off topic. It's not about computational implementation, but rather about logic. I may be mistaken though.

Answer (score 1):

Take the operation that gives you $g$ from $G$ and apply it to $(G+H)$.

Generally, forces add as vectors and the result is called net force. The net force is then used to calculate effect of forces on the future state. There are many algorithms for this, Euler, Verlet, Runge-Kutta...